# Not able to implement logging using aop

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, aop

I am trying to implement logging using aop in my project but logs are not getting displayed on console. Following are the steps I have implemented:

**Step 1. Changes in applicationContext.xml:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation=
        "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring/properties/messagingContext.properties"/>  
    <import resource="/spring-jms.xml" />  
    <import resource="/hibernate.xml" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />    
    <!-- Auto scan the components -->
     <context:component-scan base-package="com.org.myapp" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <aop:config proxy-target-class="true"/>
    <tx:jta-transaction-manager/>
    <context:annotation-config />   

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
        <aop:include name="myLogger"/>
    </aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

    <bean id="myLogger" 
        class="com.org.myapp.aspect.MyLogger">
    </bean>
</bean>
```

Step 2. Implementing Aspect

```
@Aspect
public class MyLogger{  
    @Before("execution(public * com.org.myapp.service.TargetClass.targetMethod(..))")
    public void loggingAdvice(){
        System.out.println("Entering into method");
   }
}
```

Now when I am calling the target class through a soap request the class is executing without any errors but log is not printing on the console.